# what happens when recv() called with null buffer

Tags: sockets

I'm curious to know what happens when below call is made .

```
recv(<socket no>, NULL , <lenght> , 0) ;
```

and also one more question is that , after calling recv function data on socket gets flushed or what happens really ?

Regards,
Kiran

Comment: You can just test what happens. What do you mean by "flushed"? Explain what you are doing, then perhaps more useful answers can be given.

Comment: Unless it is documented that [`recv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/recv.html) accepts a null pointer for the buffer, the answer is 'it is undefined behaviour and anything could happen'.  There's no mention of NULL, so it is undefined behaviour.  There is mention about what happens when there is more data to read than fits — depending on the socket type, the excess data may be discarded.

Comment: @CodeCaster - I was just going through existing code in our project and I'm new to our project and also new to socket programming .
So i just wanted to know once recv() called with valid buffer  data will be read from the socket and after that data on the socket will be deleted or how is it ? that was my question .

Comment: _"and after that data on the socket will be deleted or how is it?"_ - What are you afraid of, that the socket API returns the same data twice? Who cares where the data buffered by the OS remains after a succesful `recv()` call? As a socket API user you are not concerned with that. If the socket API decides to take the data out of the buffer out for a dance and a drink, you don't care, as your buffer is filled with the data you requested. So what is your **real** question? What do you expect to happen? What will you do if you get that question answered? Will you make the OS buffer differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you would even ask this question. Don't call recv() with a null buffer, that is my advice. The result is at best undefined, at worst a SIGSEGV at least.

> and also one more question is that , after calling recv function data on socket gets flushed or what happens really ?

It depends. In TCP the unread data remains to be read next time. In UDP the unread part of the datagram is discarded.

Comment: "The result is at best undefined, at worst a SIGSEGV at least." I thing a SIGSEGV is better than undefined behavior because you can't really know when there is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide a non-zero length, you'd better have a non-NULL pointer to put the data in otherwise you'll be in all sorts of trouble.

If the specified length is zero, you should get a zero return value with no data written to the buffer.

Whether or not data is discarded if the buffer provided is too small depends on the type of connection.

Comment: thanks for the response .
and also one more question is that , after calling recv function data on socket gets flushed or what happens really ?

Answer (score 0):

The return value of recv would be -1 if the buffer is NULL and the size is nonzero. I tested it and errno was set to ECONNABORTED, but that sounds like a strange error to me.

Using cygwin and gcc with posix sockets.

If you receive data and the requested size is smaller, you can repeatedly call recv to get the rest of the data. Depending on your socket being nonblocking or not recv returns -1 when the socket has no more data and errno is EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK. If it is blocking it will block until the buffer is filled or the function is interrupted.

Comment: I doubt it. More likely you would get a SIGSEGV. And recv() doesn't 'block until the buffer is filled', it blocks until at least one byte has been received. -1

Comment: Actually that was what I expected :), but when I run my code it returns with this error on cygwin. You are right about the 1 byte though.

Comment: I think Cygwin must be saving you from the real effect.

Comment: On the other hand "undefined behaviour" can also include a gracefull return with an errorcode. :)